# How to use vanilla js in reactjs to create a chart?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

```js
test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <canvas class="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can I add a `<script>js code</script>` to `myChart` on react? using chartjs.

I have a json chart data.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a ChartJs React package](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2), which you can use to avoid such patterns.

Comment: True, but I have a JSON.

Comment: @ClaytonCrockville does it matter? It will be same library, but with more convenient access ways